# How to bind Model properties with Form Textboxes?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I am new to Delphi VCL development. I am presently using Delphi 10.3. I am facing a problem binding my Model data with Textboxes on a Form.

For example, a Person model has 10 properties. To display those property values, do I have to assign the properties to Form Textboxes one by one?

```pascal
TextBox1.Text := person.FirstName;
TextBox2.Text := person.LastName;
...
```

Is there any other way of doing this task with binding or using less code??

Comment: Look at [LiveBindings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio)